# Python opencv: Draw lines between points and find full contours

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a set of three points, in a triangle. eg: [[390  37], [371 179], [555 179]]

After drawing the lines, [How to draw lines between points in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671524/how-to-draw-lines-between-points-in-opencv)

How do I find the full Contours between the lines I Just drew?

I keep receiving error below:

```
    img = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 3], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(img, triangle_vertices, 0, (0, 0, 0), -1)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

> Error:  (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your main issue is that you can only find contours on a binary image (not color). Your points also need to be in a Numpy array (as x,y pairs -- note the comma). So here is how I did it in Python/OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create black background image
img = np.zeros((500, 1000), dtype=np.uint8)

# define triangle points
points = np.array( [[390,37], [371,179], [555,179]], dtype=np.int32 )

# draw triangle polygon on copy of input
triangle = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(triangle, [points], True, 255, 1)

# find the external contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(triangle, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# get the single contour of the triangle
cntr = cntrs[0]

# draw filled contour on copy of input
triangle_filled = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(triangle_filled, [cntr], 0, 255, -1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('triangle.jpg', triangle)
cv2.imwrite('triangle_filled.jpg', triangle_filled)

cv2.imshow('triangle', triangle)
cv2.imshow('triangle_filled', triangle_filled)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Triangle Polygon Image:

[image]

Triangle Filled Contour Image:

[image]

Comment: thanks, btw, what is this line doing? cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1],  why would there be a second contour, should it always be [0] ? just curiosu

Comment: That line is used to determine how many things are returned from findContours and get only the contours not the hierarchy. Different versions of findContours returned other than 2 items (hierarchy and contours). The [0] here refers to which return item, not the first contour. The cntrs refers to all return items including both hierarchy and contours. Versions around 3.4.2 return 3 items: image, hierarchy and contours, not just hierarchy and contours, as in most versions. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

Comment: ok, one last question, whats the difference between  drawContours and polylines? they seem to be doing same thing, thanks

Comment: Not much visually. But contours can have many vertices (as many as pixels in the lines) depending upon straightness and how the contours were drawn. Contours also have a hierarchy associated with them that poly lines do not. Also if you have an image, you can find contours but you cannot find vertices for the polylines directly. But you can get vertices from the contours and reduce them often to a few vertices of simple shapes.